# css body border, absolute positioning interfering

Tags: html, css

I do not understand why the border around `body` is not rendering.  I believe it has to do with the child div, `#pages`, having absolute positioning because when I remove `#pages` the border reappears. How do I fix this?

```css
html {
  width: 100%;
}
    
body {
  background-color: green;
  background-size: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  border-style: solid;
}
    
#pages {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="pages">
  <a href="">REPORT FRAUD</a><br>
  <a href="">TRACK</a>
</div>
```

Comment: When I use the code you've provided there is a thin black border around the viewport and an x-axis scrollbar. Exactly what I would expect from the CSS you've provided.

Comment: theres a black line at the top, that is the border of body, because #pages has position: absolute it is not in document flow and wont stretch the size of body

Comment: Border across all 4 sides will be visible once height is defined in "em" or in "pixel"

Comment: @user6297534 height of.....body ? and why `px` or `em`? why not `rem` or `vh` ? why not `cm` or `mm` ? https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Comment: Its height of the body. Yes, we can use all absolute and relative lengths except percentage (%).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The border does not disappear. It's there but you have no content in the body so it doesn't have what to 'wrap' inside the border. So it appears only like a 'border-top' but in fact is a 4 sided border without any space inside it's borders :)

I say that body has no content because the only element inside it has `postion:absolute` so the #page doesn't occupy any content.

THere are a few ways to fix this. You can add a height to body of 100vh ( 100% viewport height ). And you will have no problems.

```css
    
body {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  height:100vh;
}

#pages {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="pages">
  <a href="">REPORT FRAUD</a><br>
  <a href="">TRACK</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try to add 100% to html and body tag

```
html, body { height: 100%}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
    
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  background-size: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  border-style: solid;
}
    
#pages {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="pages">
  <a href="">REPORT FRAUD</a><br>
  <a href="">TRACK</a>
</div>
```